# Why error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occurs?

Tags: java, logging

When using this code:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DeviceDAOImpl.class);
```

in class `DeviceDAOImpl`.

An error occurs: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWHbb.png)

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Without the declaration of the logger everything works fine.

Tell me, please, why the error occurs.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: How are you running your application? Is it run as main, or as executable jar or as ear/war deployed to app server?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes

Comment: @tsolakp create run/debug config -> comcat 7.0 -> build artefact, add him in dependency. Apply. Run

Comment: Is your artifact a `war`? Looks like your tomcat that is run from IDE does not see log4j jars. Make sure it either runs your app as `war` and the `war` contains `log4j-api` jar or if `war` is exploded tomcat sees your `WEB-INF` directory that should be under `target` directory.